# Calculate next month in WORD 2010

Tags: word-2010, fieldcodes, word-field

I am trying to calculate next day in Word 2010 and use the next formula in the field

```
= {DATE \@ "M" } + 1
```

But I've got an error:

```
!Syntax Error, {
```

I've tired to find why it doesn't work. It's my first experiens woth fields in Word. Please, help me with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the {} in nested field codes have to be the special field code braces that you can enter using ctrl-F9 on Windows versions of Word. (Unless, of course, the "{" or "}" are intended to be characters in a string. That particular syntax error strongly suggests that you have just typed the characters using the { and } keys on the keyboard.

Comment: Of course all this is inside the field and inside the curly braces - otherwise it will be displayed just as a text. But i've got an error when Word tries to interpret fields value.